# How to get record in true alphabetically ( case insensitive ) sort order in odoo?

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, odoo, odoo-14

My use-case is to list the records in a tree or kanban view by name but it should be case insensitive.
Current state
Eg. I have four records like

```
Apple
Orange
apple
Banana
```

In default the ordering is:

```
Apple
Banana
Orange
apple
```

And the expected ordering is:

```
Apple
apple
Banana
Orange
```

How to achieve this? Is there any ORM method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Odoo searches for records, it will attempt to construct an appropriate `ORDER BY clause` based on `order_spec`, which must be a comma-separated list of valid field names, optionally followed by an `ASC` or `DESC` direction.

The order by clause is computed based on [_order](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/1db92688d9e7bf0843edfd248ffef89c38bb66f0/odoo/models.py#L4385) attribute and can be overridden by the `order` parameter in the search function.

You can override the `_generate_order_by_inner` function to make it possible to pass function names used in SQL queries directly in `_order` attribute (`field_name:function`) for char fields.

***Example:***

```py
class Fruits(models.Model):
    _name = 'fruit.fruit'
    _order = 'name:lower'

    name = fields.Char()

    @api.model
    def _generate_order_by_inner(self, alias, order_spec, query, reverse_direction=False, seen=None):
        if seen is None:
            seen = set()
        self._check_qorder(order_spec)

        order_by_elements = []
        for order_part in order_spec.split(','):
            order_split = order_part.strip().split(' ')
            order_field = order_split[0].strip()
            order_direction = order_split[1].strip().upper() if len(order_split) == 2 else ''
            if reverse_direction:
                order_direction = 'ASC' if order_direction == 'DESC' else 'DESC'
            do_reverse = order_direction == 'DESC'
            # ------------------------------------------------------------------
            func_split = order_field.strip().split(':')
            order_field = func_split[0].strip()
            func = func_split[1].strip().upper() if len(func_split) == 2 else ''
            # ------------------------------------------------------------------
            field = self._fields.get(order_field)
            if not field:
                raise ValueError("Invalid field %r on model %r" % (order_field, self._name))
            
            if order_field == 'id':
                order_by_elements.append('"%s"."%s" %s' % (alias, order_field, order_direction))
            else:
                if field.inherited:
                    field = field.base_field
                if field.store and field.type == 'many2one':
                    key = (field.model_name, field.comodel_name, order_field)
                    if key not in seen:
                        seen.add(key)
                        order_by_elements += self._generate_m2o_order_by(alias, order_field, query, do_reverse, seen)
                elif field.store and field.column_type:
                    qualifield_name = self._inherits_join_calc(alias, order_field, query)
                    if field.type == 'boolean':
                        qualifield_name = "COALESCE(%s, false)" % qualifield_name
                    # ------------------------------------------------------
                    if func and field.type == 'char':
                        qualifield_name = "%s(%s)" % (func, qualifield_name)
                    # ------------------------------------------------------
                    order_by_elements.append("%s %s" % (qualifield_name, order_direction))
                else:
                    _logger.warning("Model %r cannot be sorted on field %r (not a column)", self._name, order_field)
                    continue  # ignore non-readable or "non-joinable" fields

        return order_by_elements
```

You can also patch the `models.BaseModel._generate_order_by_inner` to use the same logic for any char field.

***Example:***

```py
@api.model
def _generate_order_by_inner(self, alias, order_spec, query, reverse_direction=False, seen=None):
    ...

models.BaseModel._generate_order_by_inner = _generate_order_by_inner
```

To override the sort order in any view, you have just to include:

```py
if field.type == 'char':
    qualifield_name = "lower(%s)" % (qualifield_name,)
```

Without redefining the order.

Answer (score 0):

You have to think atleast about two things:

1. Using `search` (or `search_count`) to get records from the database. You can use the parameter `order` to tell Odoo which order the records should be get directly sorted by the database. So for example use `self.env['fruits'].search([], order="LOWER(name)")` to get all fruits in "true" alphabetically order on column "name".
2. The second part to think about is sorting records in python. But the same principal can be used there. Just lower- or uppercase while sorting.

A third part could be direct queries, but using them in this context would be the same like doing the "search" from point 1. Because the `order` parameter will be set in the query Odoo is building in the end of `search` anyways.

Comment: Does `self.env['fruits'].search([], order="LOWER(name)")` actually work?  I get `'Invalid "order" specified. A valid "order" specification is a comma-separated list of valid field names (optionally followed by asc/desc for the direction)'`, albeit in Odoo 11.

Comment: Oh, does Odoo really check this parameter... Okay that sucks. Tested it on Odoo 14, it's not working... Okay i will change or delete my answer.

Comment: You could use a computed field that returns `name.lower()` perhaps?

Comment: Yes and it has to be stored.

Comment: Actually [str.casefold](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) would be better than `.lower`.

Comment: I think it's time you write your answer? :-P

Comment: I was going to answer with  something fancy with collations, but ordering by a computed field is simpler and less brittle.  Anyway I'm busy today, so feel free to amend this answer :-)